# IdentityServer3 WS-Federation example Client and Server

Tags: identityserver3, ws-federation

I'm trying to get both the IdentityServer3 WS-Federation Client and a corresponding IS3 WS-Federation Provider(server) working on my local machine before progressing to a development server.

I'm using the IS3 sample MVC WS-Fed client [found here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcOwinWsFederation).
and
in a separate VS17 I'm using Scott Brady's WS-Fed plug-in Provider example [found here](https://github.com/scottbrady91/IdentityServer3-Example).

**Short Description of Problem**
When just the Provider example solution runs, I can successfully log in (as the alice/alice user) and check Client Application Permissions (though none exist) so I am confident that Scott's WS-Fed Provider is working as advertized.

However when I run the WS-Fed client example and wire it up to the WS-Fed Provider, then try to check claims on a user, here's what happens:

1. Client starts up on its own port
2. I click the claims link
3. client refers to provider IS3 WS-Fed
4. WS-Fed StackTrace on the certificate validation

   I get a StackTrace at ThrowIfContextInvalid() inside System.IdentityModel  because the get_Issuer() fails. I don't even get to the refered IS3 login screen because it fails before then.

I wager it's something dumb like the scope of the x509 cert within the server process isn't available to the client process, or maybe my client needs a token signing cert, too? (remember they are both running on the same box in two separate VS17 instances.)

Remember, I haven't coded these samples, simply extract-build-run...in order to understand the flow/connectivity before proceeding.

I did verify:
Server port and RAMMFAR
Server signing cert present
Client Provider = server port, urn, etc.

I could upload code, but it's all in the Gits just as referenced above!

*(help me ObiWan, you're my only hope; where ObiWan = @leastprivilege)*

**Screenshot of Provider asking for credentials**
[image]

**Screenshot of Provider with login credentials accepted**
[image]

**Screenshot of Client startup**
[image]

**Screenshot of StackTrace on WS-Fed provider**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into the answer found in [SO question #39362424](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39362424/in-identityserver3-the-remote-certificate-is-invalid-according-to-the-validation?rq=1) to see if this is solution to my problem...